# Is it possible to not stop an API call which is doing some operation in server side if i redirect to another page in the mean time in React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I used the post method to send some data through an API calling to Nodejs and waiting for the response after getting the response it will trigger another API. At this moment user wants to visit another page but the API calls will not be aborted. API call will do its task.
Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Call the API in redux using redux-thunk. Since redux is outside of all component. Changing page won't stop the API calling

Comment: Thanks for the information but I am afraid, The project is in context API. How can it be done in context API?

Comment: The user didn't say they were using Redux, so suggesting redux-thunk isn't really answering the question. Using it wouldn't enable them to abort an API request so I don't think this is on topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a state variable and save the response of the post request in that variable, so it will be saved

Comment: but navigating to another page will stop the API call.

Comment: Have you tried doing that? ..... because I don't think it stops the API call ( make sure it is a async function though)

Comment: It stops the API call because another page will render it's component. previous component's API calling is not working

Answer (score 0):

When I implement the APIs in express, they continue to be executed even if the user navigates away, as illustrated by this example:

```js
express()
.get("/api1", function(req, res) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("API call finished");
    res.end();
  }, 10000);
})
.get("/api2", function(req, res) {
  res.end();
})
.listen(...);
```

The user first types `http://server/api1` into their browser, which returns nothing after 10 seconds. But rather than wait, they navigate away to `http://server/api2`, which returns nothing immediately. But the `/api1` call continues, as demonstrated by the console message after 10 seconds.

How does this differ from your case?